# How Do I Implement SRP Across A Few Classes?

Tags: java, architecture, single-responsibility-principle

My friend and I are working on a game. Right now the game is very simple but we want to understand how we would go about implementing the Single Responsibility Principle between three objects. We have player, enemy, and bullet classes.

1. The player and enemy both need to be able attack and move, while the
   bullet only needs to be able to move.
2. They all need to be able to collide with one another.
3. The player moves and attacks based on user input
4. The enemy moves and attacks based on predetermined attack patterns.

We're really really struggling with the class structure and how to organize the code - we were debating using objects that just hold state and then big controller classes that each do one thing (manage collisions, manage attacking, etc.). Could someone please provide a suggested architecture that follows SRP?

Thank you!

Comment: Your last idea seems like it might be on the right track.  However, good software design is more art than science in my opinion, and requires a lot of experience and/or reading a couple good books on the subject.  I don't think we could help you much based on such a vague outline of what you want the game to do.

Comment: Sometimes you have to just come up with some design and be willing to refactor later when it starts looking like your classes are getting too complicated, or logic is being duplicated over multiple classes.  You don't have to get the design correct the first time.

Comment: Hmm alright, thanks!